# How to prove that (B^-1)(A^-1)(C^-1)(CAB) = I

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

'''A, B, C are 3 x 3 matrices and I is the identity matrix.'''

DON'T READ THE FOLLOWING:
I do not know why it is not allowing me to post the question with only the first line in the body.
Adding more sentences may solve the issue.

Comment: Hint: show your efforts. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first check matrix multiplication meets the associative property.

Then it is trivial since 
$$B^{-1}A^{-1}C^{-1}CAB=B^{-1}A^{-1}AB=B^{-1}B=I$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- Matrix multiplication is [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property)